# Npm start gives the error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-start

everyone!
I am trying to run default task on `npm run` command on Windows 10.
That is an error that I have got while using it.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 9
npm ERR! builderLight@0.0.15 start: `bower install && gulp --debug`
npm ERR! Exit status 9
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the builderLight@0.0.15 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-29T15_01_45_882Z-debug.log
```

How to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to run first: npm install or bower install